# Formatar valor p:slider jsf

Tags: java, primefaces

Olá,tenho um componente p:slider q vai de R$ 0 - R$ 5000. O problema é que não sei como formatar os valores na moeda brasileira. alguem pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Baseado no showcase Primefaces [Primefaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/slider.xhtml)

```
    <h:outputText id="output" value="R$ #{testeView.total}" />
    <h:inputHidden id="txt2" value="#{testeView.total}" />
    <p:slider for="txt2" display="output" style="width: 200px" displayTemplate="R$ {value}" maxValue="5000" minValue="0" />
```